# Run runnable JARs on button click from html

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, jar

I have created testing automated script for all functions of my mobile application. so it runs fine manually from eclipse. I am using selenium web driver and java.

Now I want to create **GUI/Easy interface** where I can give dropdown of all methods with button called **RUN** ,so when tester select method and run then that particular function script will run automation script.

I have exported all functions as Runnable JAR , So now I need to know how can I call and run these runnable jar from html page?on click.  Is there any easy way for this?

I have found some answers and they are suggesting to use applet but I am finding some another way if possible.

Answer (score 0):

you may achieve it through batch file or sh file.

just sample code to run jar from web

```
String jarPath=request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("")+"/myjar.exe";

                if (osname.indexOf("nux") >= 0 || osname.indexOf("nix") >= 0) 
                {
                    //for sending  request to sh file
                    filePath = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("")+"/WEB-INF/classes/";

                    cmdList.add("sh");
                    cmdList.add("CallJar.sh");
                    cmdList.add(dbUser.getUserName());
                    cmdList.add(dbUser.getPassword());

                    cmdList.add(jarPath);
                }
                else
                {
                    // for windows
                    String jrePath="";
                    String f="C:/Windows/SysWOW64";
                    if(new File(f).exists())
                    {
                        jrePath="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre6\\bin\\java";
                        jrePath="\""+jrePath+"\"";
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        jrePath="C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre6\\bin\\java";
                        jrePath="\""+jrePath+"\"";
                    }
                    filePath = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("")+"\\WEB-INF\\classes\\";
                    //filePath="\"" + filePath + "\"";

                    syncStatusLogFilePath="\""+syncStatusLogFilePath+"\"";
                    jarPath="\""+jarPath+"\"";
                    cmdList.add("cmd");
                    cmdList.add("/c");
                    cmdList.add("CallJar.bat");
                    cmdList.add(jarPath);
                    cmdList.add(jrePath);
```

hope you may get some idea.